# Can't connect to local SQL database with connection string ,'Form1' does not contain a definition for 'Properties'

Tags: c#, sql, forms, properties, connection-string

I am trying to connect my local SQL database to a c# forms application but it won't read data from the file.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string connectionString = Form1.Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally your `Settings` class should be under `<DefaultProjectNameSpace>.Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString` where `<DefaultProjectNameSpace>` is the namespace of your project/application.

If it is not there try to locate it from your project under the Properties folder.

Comment: That worked but in turn gave me an error for 'ConnectionString' saying that it does not have a definition in 'settings'

Comment: Have you added this property in your settings? Go to your Project-->Properties-->Settings on your Solution Explorer and double click Settings. Add that property there.

Comment: that worked but now something else isnt working :/ thanks for the help

Answer (score -1):

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MediaMantradb" connectionString="data source=.;database=MediaMantradb; integrated security=true; trusted_connection=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
 </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: @Tom : You must declare connectionStrings in web config file.

Comment: @Tom : i try out some MediaMantradb database name.